# How to create a Notched Shape in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

Trying to figure out how to build something similar to the images but with no result. I tried to use `CircularNotchedRectangle`  code and put it inside a `CustomPainter` but couldn't figure out how to adjust it.

any suggestions will be appreciated!!

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? Please mark it correct, so that other users may benefit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Flutter Shape Maker](https://fluttershapemaker.com) online tool. With the help of this you can create your custom shape and it will give you a code for that shape.

Answer (score 2):

You can have it on the `bottomNavitationBar` property of the `Scaffold` and use the `BottomAppBar` widget with a `notchMargin` and a `shape` to put your `CircularNotchedRectangle`:

```
Scaffold(
  ...
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    notchMargin: 6.0,
    shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        ...
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```